# How can I customize a property's regex for AutoFixture?

Tags: autofixture

I just changed my `[RegularExpression]` validation and a third of my unit tests broke!

It turns out AutoFixture is generating values based on that regex, which is cool, but it doesn't understand all regexs, so I'd like to supply it with a simpler one:

```
Fixtures.Customize<Details>(c => c.With(d => d.PhoneNumber,
     new SpecimenContext(Fixtures).Resolve(
     new RegularExpressionRequest(@"[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}"))));
```

This ends up giving me a generic LINQ error ("Sequence contains no elements.") at object creation time.  What am I doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there any way I can just turn this feature off?  `Customize()` is helpful, but it prevents me from using `Build()` without repeating all the same logic.  (Doesn't it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't easily turn that feature off, but you can easily override it:

```
public class Details
{
    [RegularExpression(@"?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class DetailsTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void OverridePhoneNumberRegularExpression()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var pattern = @"[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}";
        var phoneNumber =
            new SpecimenContext(fixture).Resolve(
                new RegularExpressionRequest(pattern));
        fixture.Customize<Details>(c => c
            .With(x => x.PhoneNumber, phoneNumber));
        var sut = fixture.Create<Details>();

        var actual = sut.PhoneNumber;

        Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch(actual, pattern));
    }
}
```

This test passes and looks similar to the one shown in the question. – What other members are defined in `Details` class?

Comment: Well, breaking it out as in your example worked for me, though there doesn't appear to be a difference.  I must have had a typo in my original construction?!  At any rate, thank you for the help!